# What is the use case for RawContact DATA_SET?

Tags: android, contactscontract, rawcontacts

According to Android documentation ([ContactsContract.RawContacts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html)), the DATA_SET column provides another degree of uniqueness.

> The data set within the account that this row belongs to. This allows
>   multiple sync adapters for the same account type to distinguish
>   between each others' data. The combination of ACCOUNT_TYPE,
>   ACCOUNT_NAME, and DATA_SET identifies a set of data that is associated
>   with a single sync adapter.

I'm simply not understanding the use case. If there are two accounts with the same type and name, but different DATA_SET values, are they really two separate accounts with their own sets of contacts? Why does this occur? Why not just require different names and eliminate the DATA_SET column?

Comment: I have discovered one use case, not for my usage but for another person.  For that person, the Settings table contains two rows for every gmail account. One with dataset = null, the other with dataset = "plus". This duplication only happens for Settings. Groups has no rows for the "plus" case. Nor do RawContacts.